# Invalid Operation when attempting to run tcl code

Tags: command-line, scripts

Using terminal, I am attempting to execute a script containing tcl code named `myscript.tcl`. According to the tutorial I am following, I am to type `chmod +x myscript.tcl` then run the code using `./myscript.tcl`. Note, in the tcl script I also added `#!/home/localadmin/Desktop` to the script per the tutorial. However, upon execution, I get the error `Invalid Operation`. Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

Precise error: `E: Invalid operation ./myscript.tcl`

Link to tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5m_vuBzdZE&list=PL7616FA0112D74AD3&index=2 , refer to 1:10

The code :

```
#variables set to integer will ALWAYS be integer, cannot assign strings
set x 3

set y 4

#$x means the value of x
#whatever happens after expr will take it as a mathematical expression
#whatever inside brackets is executed
set z [expr $x + $y]

#text is option for command label
#the . represents anything coming from main window after execution
label .sum -text "z is $z"

label .myname -text "My NAME is RAND PAUL"

incr z

label .increment -text "incrementing z -> $z"

#pack puts the previous labels on te main window
#without pack, will discard the labels
pack .myname .increment .sum
```

Follow up:

Another script I have -

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh


#Lesson 3 tk/tcl lists


set to_do [list]
lappend to_do "name"
lappend to_do "is"
lappend to_do "bobby"
lappend to_do "jones"

set num [list 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11]
puts $to_do
puts $num
puts "index 0 is [lindex $to_do 0]"
puts "index 3 is [lindex $to_do 3]"
puts "replacing one element..."
puts [lreplace $num 3 3 [list 30 40 50 60]]
puts "replacing a range of elements from index 3 till ndex 6 => other indexees from 4 till 6 will deleted"
puts [lreplace $num 3 6 [list 30 40 50 60]]

puts "inserting one element at index 1 (2nd element that is)..."
puts [linsert $num 1 "new list element"]
```

Produces the same error: `E: Invalid operation ./lesson3.tcl`.
I used the same `shebang` found in this new file in the original post and it fixed it, however, I still have the same error while attempting to run this new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the reason your script is not running, is becuase your `shebang` is completely wrong. The point of the `shebang` is to tell the compiler what package or program to run the script with `#!/home/localadmin/Desktop` points to nothing the comipler cares about (i'm guessing)

Everything else looks right so far (again I am unfamiliar with `tcl`) So I would try changing the first line in the script to something like the following

#### myscript.tcl

```
 #!/usr/bin/tclsh
 my_script.....
```

Assuming this doesn't work, you can track down any errors you have that would prevent the script from running (such as syntax errors and the like) by running

```
tclsh your_script.tcl
```

After watching the video, this tutorial does not pertain to you (assuming you really are running ubuntu) for how to run the script

Comment: Running tclsh your_script.tcl worked for me, nvm thank you